# If statement based on other column

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, if-statement, switch-statement

I have a select statement:

```
select DATEDIFF(day,[Contract Start Date],[Contract End Date]) as contract_time
from table 1
```

now, how to add into next column if statement:

```
contract_time >= 390 then display A
contract_time < 390 then display B
contract_time is null display C? (because Contract start date or End date can be null)
```

thanks for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [case expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx):

```
;With cte as 
(
select DATEDIFF(day,[Contract Start Date],[Contract End Date]) as contract_time,
a,
b,
c
from table 1
)

select contract_time
       case when contract_time is null then c
            when contract_time >= 390 then a
            when contract_time <  390 then b
       end as otherColumn
from cte
```

note that a, b and c must be all of the same data type.

Answer (score 0):

Use IIF function which supports in SQL Server 2012 otherwise you can also use CASE WHEN...THEN ...END

```
;With cte_table1 as 
(
   SELECT 
       DATEDIFF(day,[Contract Start Date],[Contract End Date]) as contract_time,
       A,
       B,
       C
   FROM [table 1]
)

SELECT contract_time,
       IIF(contract_time is null,C,
           IIF(contract_time >= 390, A,B))
       as otherColumn
FROM cte_table1
```

Comment: iif is just syntactic sugar for case expressions - see the remarks section in it's [msdn page.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx) Of course, this solution would work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, [Contract Start Date], [Contract End Date]) AS contract_time
    ,CASE 
        WHEN DATEDIFF(day, [Contract Start Date], [Contract End Date]) IS NULL
            THEN c
        WHEN DATEDIFF(day, [Contract Start Date], [Contract End Date]) >= 390
            THEN a
        WHEN DATEDIFF(day, [Contract Start Date], [Contract End Date]) < 390
            THEN b
        END AS otherColumn
FROM TABLE
```

Comment: That's exactly why I've used a cte - to only write the `datediff` once. Of course, this solution would work fine.

Comment: @Zohar Peled: Your code looks good. I want to make it easy to understand but lengthy.